# How to automate SQL Server query and automatically put the results in an Excel file

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, automation

Currently have a lot of queries to run on the first of the month and on Mondays of every week in Microsoft SQL Server. Does anyone know how I could automate the 
queries to run on their own and then put the results in an Excel file?

Comment: SSIS - use Excel File Destination to output your results, deploy the job to your SQL Server and schedule them to suit your needs.

Comment: Can you tell us what version and edition of SQL Server you are using?  If you are not using SQL Server Express you can use SQL Server Integration Services to export the data and a SQL Agent job to schedule it for your automation.

Comment: Currently Using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1):

the easiest thing is probably to set up reports in Report Server (SSRS) to execute your SQL and render them into the appropriate format. You can then schedule the reports to run on whatever days you want and email the results exported into an Excel file.